# .htaccess rewrite root to folder, yet block direct urls to same folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been researching and trying for a week to accomplish this, but I haven't been able to find my solution.  I'm sure it's possible, but I'm just not an expert in the depths of voodoo magic.

The setup:

- An installation of MantisBT located in
  mysite.com/mantisbt/currentver/mantis-1.3.19
- When I perform an upgrade, I want to archive all old versions and old
  database dumps to /mantisbt/oldversions/ to keep things tidy.
- I also have other utilities and pages in various subdirectories, for
  instance "mysite.com/utils"

The goal:

- I want users to type in mysite.com/ (root) and have the URL rewritten
  (transparently) to /mantisbt/currentver/mantis-1.3.19/ so that they
  don't see my directory structure and it looks like the mantisbt app is
  located in the root directory.
- I also want protection from anyone trying to directly access a
  subdirectory beginning with "/mantis". For instance, if 
  someone directly types mysite.com/mantisbt/currentver/mantis-1.3.19/
  into their browser, I want them redirected back to the root directory
  so they access the site from root just like everyone else.
- I also need to allow my other subdirectories like mysite.com/utils to
  be accessible if I type in the full path to them.

The biggest problem I've encountered is that Apache loops through your .htaccess file again every time the URL changes.  So I get stuck in these rewrite loops.  I've tried looking at every possible tool that Apache offers, but I'm seriously outgunned here.  I could provide examples of what I've tried, they're obviously not correct, but ask me and I can post them.

Comment: Please share some code.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be far better off altering the **DocumentRoot** in your **httpd.conf**, and mapping in the **utils** directory, via a **Location** directive. It will be far cleaner, and Apache won't have to do some trickery with every request.

Anyway something along the following lines should work.

```
# Stop direct access
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule /?mantisbt/currentver/mantis-1.3.19 / [NC,L,R=301]

# Internally Rewrite everything apart from /utils to /mantisbt/mantis-1.3.19/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !mysite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/utils [NC]
RewriteRule .* /mantisbt/currentver/mantis-1.3.19%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: The %{HTTP_REFERER} check is genius. I was wondering if something like this existed. I'll try it and report back.

Comment: Just curious about how Apache works. Is it possible for an outside user to craft a custom request and spoof the %{HTTP_REFERER} so that fakes out Apache into thinking the request is coming from itself?

Comment: Yes, HTTP Headers are hackable.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I think protecting against something like that for my site is a little too paranoid.  But if I did want to protect against a spoof, would I need to drop into the httpd.conf file to achieve my goals? Or is there another secure way to detect whether the .htaccess file had been looped through once before? Maybe I'm hitting the limits of .htaccess are in this regard.

Comment: There are half a dozen ways to make things a bit securer, but all still breakable. You could set a cookie, via a rewrite rule, on the first request for something app specific, and then insist on both the referer and cookie be present for all other requests.